# Halting a translate3d transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a scrolling text div that I would like the user to be able to pause and resume with the click of a button. Here's how I'm creating the transition:

```
words.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, -"+(27 * (words.children.length-4))+"px, 0px)";
words.style.webkitTransition = ((27 * words.children.length)/speed)+"s all linear";
```

I've tried to set the transform to "none" in the pause function, but that just makes the div scroll back to where it previously was. It's the equivalent of doing translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px). Is there a method to simply pause the current animation, or would I have to somehow measure the current transition position?

Update: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VAgXF/1/

Comment: My best bet would be to remove the transition attr and calc the current position. Then set the transition to the remainder on resume.

Comment: If instead of using a transition you used an animation, you could use animationstate = paused. Would that be ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit based on live example**

[**Try this demo instead**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/VAgXF/5/)

You can use `WebKitCSSMatrix` in your case to get the `translate3d` values. I don't know all the selectors for it, but `e` is `x` and `f` is `y`, so this bit of code works since you don't change the `z`

```
var words = document.getElementById("words");
var speed = 10;
words.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, -"+(27 * (words.children.length))+"px, 0px)";
words.style.webkitTransition = ((27 * words.children.length)/speed)+"s all linear";

var paused = false;
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  if(!paused) {
    var translated3D = new WebKitCSSMatrix(window.getComputedStyle(words, null).webkitTransform);
    words.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(" + translated3D.e + "px, " + translated3D.f + "px, " + 0 + "px)";
    paused = true;
    button.innerHTML = "Start";
  } else {
    paused = false;
    button.innerHTML = "Stop";
    words.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0px, -"+(27 * (words.children.length))+"px, 0px)";
    words.style.webkitTransition = ((27 * words.children.length)/speed)+"s all linear";
  }
}
```

That being said I would avoid `transform3d` for some this simple, it over complicates the issue.

Comment: I have a jsfiddle now in the question, and I've also created one with your solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/VAgXF/4/ . I get the drifting downward effect with yours.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Seems to work perfectly, as near as I can tell. Thanks!